# onActivityResult not called on back button

Tags: android

I'm having an issue with my "back button" on my android app.  I have an Activity called DashboardActivity that calls AskQuestionActivity.  I pass a value to AskQuestionActivity, and want to send that value back to DashboardActivity when the back button is pressed.  This is my code so far.  The child class is:

```
public class AskQuestionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int userId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ask_question);
    setUserId(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id"));
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent resultData = getIntent();
    resultData.putExtra("id", getUserId());
    setResult(2, resultData);
    finish();
//    super.onBackPressed();
 }

public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

}
```

The parent class is:

```
public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int userId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);
        setUserId(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id"));
        DisplayMetrics dm = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

        RelativeLayout linearLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.dashboard);

        TextView availableQuestions = new TextView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        relativeLayout.setMargins(convertDpToPx(100,dm), convertDpToPx(40,dm), convertDpToPx(0,dm), convertDpToPx(0, dm));
        availableQuestions.setLayoutParams(relativeLayout);
        User u = getUser(this.userId);

        if (u.getAvailableQuestionCount() > 0) {
            availableQuestions.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        } else {
            availableQuestions.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
        availableQuestions.setText("" + u.getAvailableQuestionCount());
        linearLayout.addView(availableQuestions);
    }

    public void askQuestion(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AskQuestionActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", getUserId());
        startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
    }

    /**
     * gets the logged in user and populates the entity
     * @return
     */
    private User getUser(int id) {
        MySQLiteHelper mDbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] selectionArgs = {String.valueOf(id)};
        Cursor cursor = db.query("user", null, "id=?", selectionArgs, null, null, null, null);
        User u = new User(new Long(id));

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            u.setUsername(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("username")));
            u.setPassword(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("password")));
            u.setAvailableQuestionCount(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("availableQuestionsCount"))));
            u.setAnswerCount(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("answerCount"))));
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        return u;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            setUserId(data.getIntExtra("id", 0));
        }
    }
        /**
         * getter for userId
         * @return
         */
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    /**
     * setter for userId
     * @param userId
     */
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    private int convertDpToPx(int dp, DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
        float pixels = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, displayMetrics);
        return Math.round(pixels);
    }

    }
```

and my manifest file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.amk27.pollit" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".CreateAccountActivity"
            android:label="CreateAccountActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".DashboardActivity"
            android:label="DashboardActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".AskQuestionActivity"
            android:label="AskQuestionActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".DashboardActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".DashboardActivity" />
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

The problem seems to be that in the parent class, onActivityResult is never called.  onCreate seems to be called instead.  I'm not sure what is causing this, so if anyone could shed some light on the situation, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have Don't Keep Activities turned on?  In that case onCreate would be called first, then onActivityResult.

Comment: `requestCode` read the doc for that parameter

Comment: you say `onActivityResult` is not called, but did you put a breakpoint at the begining of the function to see if that was really the case?

Comment: @ Gabe - I am using an emulator...from what I read, isn't that a hardware option?

Comment: @njzk2 - I did put a breakpoint, and onCreate was called first.  My code is set up so that if onCreate is called first when the back button is hit, an NPE will occur.  I assumed that onActivityResult, if implemented correctly, would be called first in this case.  Am I right?

Comment: obviously not, since you observed yourself that onCreate was called first.

Comment: Well I wasn't sure whether I had my code implemented correctly, so yes, I can see the onCreate was called first, but I wasn't sure if this was happening because of design, or because of a bug in my code (from what I read, it seemed that onActivityResult should have been called first).  That said, I commented out the part that caused an NPE when the back button is pressed, and onActivityResult was still not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was confusing the up button with the back button.  I didn't realize the difference.  After reading about the 2, the problem became clear.  onActivityResult works for the back button, as many of you pointed out, but for the up button, you need to use onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item).

Answer (score 0):

```
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultData);
```

Activity.RESULT_OK is 1? because when you start activity for result, you set your request code to 1

Comment: Ah, so apparently it is-1...I thought it was 1. I changed them to be the same number, but that onActivityResult is still not called :(

Comment: Instead of using data.getIntExtra("id", 0), use data.getStringExtra("id"); then cast back to int

Comment: My problem seems to be that the method itself is never called, so I didn't think that changing this would really fix the issue.  Still, I tried it...no luck

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use

```
 startActivityForResult(intent,code)

@Override  
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
         user.setName(data.getStringExtra("name"))
        Toast.makeText(this, data.getStringExtra("name"), 1).show();
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
    }
```

Comment: Given that some of the code from your block is from a different project, which part, specifically, are you suggesting I try?